# How to stop android notification from repeating itself

Tags: android, notifications, battery, batterymanager

I'm trying to push a notification whenever battery status is below 5% but I want it once only. With below code it's keep on repeating unless battery level gets out of condition.

```
else if((level<=5)&(level>0)){
                batteryState.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_batterylow);
                Notification notificationobject=new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this,Notifications.CHANNEL_1_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                        .setContentTitle("Battery Warning")
                        .setContentText("Your battery is low, please plugin the charger.")
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                        .build();
                mNotificationManagerCompatObject.notify(1,notificationobject);
            }
```

Comment: To be really clever, since it looks like you are using an ImageView (batteryState.setImageResource) you could use the `setTag` / `getTag` property of the view to keep a flag or any object to help you keep track of state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable to check if you have called this method already or not :

```
boolean isCalled = false;

else if((level<=5)&(level>0)){
//if you did not called your method once
if(isCalled == false){
            //make sure that this will only get called once
            isCalled = true;
            batteryState.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_batterylow);
            Notification notificationobject=new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this,Notifications.CHANNEL_1_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                    .setContentTitle("Battery Warning")
                    .setContentText("Your battery is low, please plugin the charger.")
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                    .build();
            mNotificationManagerCompatObject.notify(1,notificationobject);
           }
        }
```

Comment: It's still repeating.